# javascript combining public and private window.onload

Tags: javascript, namespaces

i am currently learning about javascript namespaces as i build a website and i have the following requirements: i want to make all of my code private so that other public scripts on the page (possibly adverts, i'm not too sure at this stage) cannot override or alter my javascript. the problem i am foreseeing is that the public scripts may use `window.onload` and i do not want them to override my private version of `window.onload`. i do still want to let them run `window.onload` though.

so far i have the following layout:

```
//public code not written by me - i'm thinking this will be executed first
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('pub').onclick = function() {
        alert('ran a public event');
    };
};

//private code written by me
(function() {
    var public_onload = window.onload; //save the public for later use
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('priv').onclick = function() {
            a = a + 1
            alert('ran a private event. a is ' + a);
        };
    };
    if(public_onload) public_onload();
    var a = 1;
})();
```

i have quite a few questions about this...

firstly, is this a good structure for writing my javascript code, or is there a better one? (i'm planning on putting all of my code within the anonymous function). is my private code really private, or is there a way that the public javascript can access it? i'm guessing the answer to this is "yes - using tricky eval techniques. do not embed code you do not trust", but i'd like to know how this would be done if so.

secondly, when i click on the public link, the event is not fired. why is this?

finally, if i comment out the `if(public_onload) public_onload();` line then `a` is returned correctly when i click the private button. but if i leave this line in then `a`'s value is nan. why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach event listeners to avoid their overriding in some way like this:

```
<ol id="res"></ol>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var res = document.getElementById('res');

    function log(line) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = line;
        res.appendChild(li);
    }

    // global code:
    window.onload = function() {
        log('inside the global window.onload handler');
    };

    // private code:
    (function(window) {
        function addEvent(el, ev, fn) {
            if (el.addEventListener) {
                el.addEventListener(ev, fn, false);
            } else if (el.attachEvent) {
                el.attachEvent('on' + ev, fn);
            } else {
                el['on' + ev] = fn;
            }
        }
        addEvent(window, 'load', function() {
            log('inside the second window.onload handler in "private section"');
        });
    })(window); 
</script>​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/TgYWN/)

The example of code organization you asked about:

**HTML:**

`<ol id="res"></ol>​`

**JavaScript:**

```
/* app.js */

// in global scope:    
var MyApp = (function(app) {
    var res = document.getElementById('res');

    app.log = function(line) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = line;
        res.appendChild(li);
    };

    app.doWork = function() {
        app.log('doing a work');
    };

    return app;
})(MyApp || {});

/* my-app-module.js */

// again in global scope: 
var MyApp = (function(app) {

    app.myModule = app.myModule || {};

    app.myModule.doWork = function () {
        app.log('my module is doing a work');
    };

    return app;
})(MyApp || {});

/* somewhere after previous definitions: */

(function() {
    MyApp.doWork();
    MyApp.myModule.doWork();
})();
```

​[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/7tBff/)

[**MyApp is accessible from outside**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/5VJws/)
[**Nothing is accessible from outside**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/Q8bJG/)

Comment: thanks for the answers man. i didn't think of passing in the `window` object to the private 'module' in your first example. i guess i thought `window` would be global within the private module...

in your second example of code organisation, i was hoping to keep my module completely inaccessible to the other public code - ie not readable or writable. would this simply mean changing `(MyApp || {})` to `()` ?

Comment: If you'll change it so, then you'll not be able to extend your initial namespace in other files. Here in my example the `MyApp` variable is shared between modules and it provides a public interface to your application.

Comment: ah i see. i plan on putting everything inside one "module" for the whole project anyway - with the hope of keeping it inaccessible. if i expose the `MYApp` object like this then couldn't other scripts write to `MyApp` and either prevent me from creating a method (if my code runs second) or overwrite some of my methods (if my code runs first)?

Comment: If you're not planning to use more than one module (.js file), you can use your approach with creating and calling an anonymous function without arguments.

Comment: So if you'll use my approach, then the `MyApp` variable will be accessible outside and another code can override the properties of `MyApp` object.
Say after your definition of `MyApp = (function(app) { ... return app;` other code can do something like `MyApp.doWork = function() { alert('doing nothing! :P'); };`

Comment: I've added to demos at the tail of my answer. Review them.

Comment: that last jsfiddle is very good and clear - thanks. just one more question regarding that though - i notice you have put `({})` instead of just `()` after the module definition there. i know `{}` is an empty object, so what then is `()`? is it implicitly an empty object?

Comment: No, just the `()` means you didn't pass any arguments to your anonymous function. So the `app` in my example will be `undefined` in this way. Then you can just create the `app` object inside the body of your anonymous function.

Comment: ah i think i see - passing in `{}` is the same as passing in nothing then doing `app = {}` on the first line of the module.